# Swap functions of command and control for editors on certain sites

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

I'm using Mac but have mostly changed os settings to fit windows style.
for moving across text cmd + arrow moves a word in some direction and ctrl + arrow moves whole line.
Some text editors on certain sites don't inherit os commands but have their own I assume.

Is there anyway I can swap the functionality of these buttons on certain text editors only to still work as intended?
So basically swap cmd and ctrl

Thanks.

Comment: This question crops up frequently. There is no good way to achieve what you want. Just set it all back to defaults & learn to live with it. Mac has one more modifier key than Win or nix, so the possibilities are greater. Many terminals & text editors use both cmd & ctrl to achieve different things. Trying to squeeze that additional functionality back into Windows' limited feature set is just never going to work.